# How to change JGroups cluster coordinator in older jgroups version

Tags: jgroups

I'm using an older version of JGroups (2.12.2) in a distributed Java application.

At some point I need to make the current cluster coordinator node not cluster coordinator anymore. So that a different (random, but not the current one) node takes over.

**Question 1:** What is the correct way to do this?

Currently I'm simply disconnecting from the cluster and  reconnecting back after a few seconds:

```
channel.disconnect();
...
channel.connect(clusterName);
```

**Question 2:** how long should I wait before connecting back? If I reconnect immediately does this still work (does another node become coordinator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, 2.12.2 is too old, I recommend upgrade to a more recent version!

Question 1: Yes, this certainly works. An alternative would be to use the approach described in [1]. You can also determine the next view programmatically; in [1], the old coord moves to the end of the list, but the view can be determined by user code. Check the JGroups manual for custom view generation.

Question 2: disconnect() and connect() don't need a sleep time in between.

[1] https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/wiki/Changing-the-coordinator-of-a-cluster